# download PDF file with ajax and function call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, download

I am trying to download the file using this function but I am not able to execute the function after first ajax success. I read other resources but it was not helpful, I am trying to achieve this from 2 days and regularly searching nothing happend.

Please helpme to create this function after first success response it will call the function as DownloadFile();

I am returning these array in the first success response -

current no any error showing only the first success response show and downlaodfile() function not run.

```
filename: "PO_21-22_0166.pdf"
path: "./folder/myfilename.pdf"
responseCode: "200"
status: "success"
```

Please help me, how I make it correct so I can download the file with the help of my created own code.
Where I am doing mistake and how it will after fix.

```js
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "example.com",
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.responseCode == '200') {
      var fileName = response.filename;
      var myurl = response.path;

      function DownloadFile(fileName) {
        //var myurl = response.path;
        $.ajax({
          url: myurl,
          cache: false,
          xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                  xhr.responseType = "blob";
                } else {
                  xhr.responseType = "text";
                }
              }
            };
            return xhr;
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
            var blob = new Blob([data], {
              type: "application/octetstream"
            });

            //Check the Browser type and download the File.
            var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
            if (isIE) {
              window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
              var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
              link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
              var a = $("<a />");
              a.attr("download", fileName);
              a.attr("href", link);
              $("body").append(a);
              a[0].click();
              $("body").remove(a);
            }
          },
        });
      }
    } else {
      alert(response.message);
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Please provide debugging information. There's ***a lot*** of things that can go wrong there to stop the download functionality working. Have you ensured the AJAX request is working? Is the element being created in the DOM? Any errors appearing in the console?

Comment: there is no error in console